# Modulus in ArcGIS Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

How to apply modulus operations (|) in ArcGIS?

For example like in:

```
|x-y|/|x+y|
```

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Abs()` (absolute value) tool.

(See:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/abs.htm)

(It took me a while to figure out what you meant, since in programming, 'modulus' or 'modulo' usually refers to the '%' or 'mod' operator for getting the remainder from a division.